# JSSOR with jQuery single image issue on skin thumbnail-navigator-07

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jssor

I have big problem here and it seems i dont know that much jQuery so i need help. If someone know this i will be grateful.
I copy everything from their folders and i want to use skin thumbnail 07. Everything was ok when my page stays in ''skin'' folder, but when i take it out, JSSOR showing me just one picture. I cant figure it out where i need to change code...that i dont need to put every single page in ''skin'' folder.

You can check my working code [here](http://stefanrepac.com/PD/skin/digitalna_stampa.php)
And not good one [here](http://stefanrepac.com/PD/digitalna_stampa.php)
Only difference is different place of .php file
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

js file reference path is incorrect.

please replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: I cant belive that was the only problem! Thank you so much! You make my day :)